# Inductor with DC and AC

Tags: electric-circuits, inductance

When a  dc voltage source is connected with a pure inductor

And the switch is closed

We get a change in voltage across inductor and along with it a also an attempt to change the current across the inductor.

We get equal and opposite voltage across inductor against the source voltage(Faraday and Lenz law) at $t = 0$.

But then as time passes we get increase /change in current across the inductor at a constant rate. di/dt = V/L.

Now when we connect ac with a pure inductor.

We have always changing voltage across the inductor and consequently always changing current across the inductor.

So can i assume that for every infinitesimal change in voltage and current across the inductor in case of ac there will always be equal and opposite voltage across the inductor which will block the current initially for a while for that  infinitesimal change and then will allow the current to change at a constant rate for that infitesimal change of voltage and current?

Comment: If you connect an _ideal_ voltage source to an _ideal_ inductor with _ideal_ wires, then the voltage across the inductor must be equal to the voltage produced by the source. Kirchoff said so.

Answer (score -1):

The inductor only reacts to the change of current in the circuit. In the DC case when you turn on the switch at t=0, the current goes from zero to some constant value it is only during that short span of time that the voltage across the inductor changes in an opposite manner. After you reach a steady-state the inductor acts like a short.

Comment: You are describing the case where there is constant resistance in series with the inductance. If the circuit consists only of an _ideal_ voltage source (no internal resistance) and an _ideal_ inductor (no resistance), connected by _ideal_ wires, then the theory predicts that the current will increase at a constant rate forever. Any _practical_ circuit, however, will have series resistance in the inductor, series resistance in the power supply, and series resistance in the connecting wires.

Comment: The voltage across the inductor  $V_L = di/dt$ depends only on the rate of change of current in the circuit. In the DC case when you maintain a constant current the voltage across the inductor becomes zero.

Comment: Yes, If you connect an ideal inductor to an ideal, constant current source, then the voltage across the inductor will be zero. But, the OP wasn't asking about a current source. The OP asked about a _voltage_ source. You can conclude from the same differential equation, that if $V_L$ is a positive constant (because, connected to the constant voltage source), then the rate of change of current must be the same positive, constant value. I.e., the current will increase at a constant rate, forever.

Comment: That makes no sense! First of all, if you have a perfect inductor such as a superconducting coil you cannot voltage bias because it is a conductor. On the other hand, what you suggest violates the conservation of energy and Faraday's law.  cannot have a voltage source with no internal resistance

Comment: Ideal voltage sources, current sources, inductors and other components is all electronics 101—first year undergrad stuff. You can read about it in the textbooks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like you have a tenuous grasp on physics and you have just memorized a bunch of definitions from your electronics 101. I suggest you go back and review your Physics 101 textbook.